# Where are variables stored?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Where are variables stored in javascript when we run pages in the browser?

Also, where I need further insight into memory organisation in terms of javascript variables , usgae and scope, and storage.
Like we say in C/C++ : local variables are stored in Stack, Dyanamic memory allocation in Heap area, and program code are stored in program area.

Comment: [These search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=where+are+javascript+variables+stored&oq=where+are+javascript+&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l3j0i22i30l7.37509384.37512311.0.37513085.21.19.0.2.2.0.269.1745.11j5j1.17.0....0...1c.1.53.serp..2.19.1747.oBuIhY1Ed0I) should answer this question.

Comment: Also, see this related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: i am aware of scope. But can you please tell me about the memory organization . ?????? @AndersonGreen

Comment: @MayurRahul: The point is that you don't need to care about. Closure scopes need to be stored on the heap, and engines do certain optimisations to store on the stack whatever they can.

Comment: The variables are stored on little yellow post-it notes stuck on the refrigerator door. Why do you care exactly?

Comment: I am curious to know exactly what happen behind the scene. Just for knowledge purpose.

Comment: @MayurRahul: It's dependent on the engine. Just imagine that everything goes onto the heap.

Comment: OK @Bergi.
Still I just want to ask, that engine might be interacting with the CPU resource (for memory storage). rite ??

Comment: Well, if you really want to know how a compiler works, you may want to read into the engine code/docs. [They](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_engines)'re mostly open source.

Comment: Also see Mike West's [Scope in JavaScript](https://mikewest.org/2006/09/scope-in-javascript). He's active in the W3C standards process and a very good writer.

Comment: @torazaburo: *"Why do you care exactly?"* - I'm not sure it really matters, but here's a for instance... he might be writing WebKit exploits. WebKit makes regular appearances on Bugtraq and Full Disclosure, and its a healthy research target.

Comment: yeah thanks all for giving some direction. I am looking into thoes.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where Window object is stored ???